# ObservableList and tableView

Tags: javafx

I have problem with show my tableView. I work with JavaFX and Hibernate.
I download data from DB to lit and I converted to `ObservableList`. It is working, I check it in console. I want that `ObservableList` show in `TableView`.

```
@FXML
private TableView<Lekarz> tableviewlekarz;

        List<Lekarz> list = session1.createCriteria(Lekarz.class).list();
        ObservableList<Lekarz> getLekarz=FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);

        TableColumn<Lekarz,String> imieColumn= new TableColumn<>("imie");
        imieColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("imie"));

         TableColumn<Lekarz,String> nazwiskoColumn= new TableColumn<>("nazwisko");
        nazwiskoColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nazwisko"));

         TableColumn<Lekarz,String> peselColumn= new TableColumn<>("pesel");             
        peselColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("pesel"));



        tableviewlekarz= new TableView<>();
        tableviewlekarz.setItems(getLekarz);
        tableviewlekarz.getColumns().addAll(imieColumn,nazwiskoColumn,peselColumn);
```

`TableView` is empty

Comment: and most probably incorrect useage of PropertyValueFactory .. tripple-check the spelling!

Comment: Ok, fault was in "tableviewlekarz= new TableView<>();"